# How to make WebLogic log all "console" message into a file?

Tags: logging, weblogic, io-redirection

In Eclipse you can see all messages in console (output of `System.out.println`), but in WebLogic, how can I get a file which contains all these message ?

Answer (score 15):

You can do this by either modifying the `startWeblogic.cmd` or from the Admin console

See both options in [detail at the docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/logging/config_logs.html#wp1022848)

When you start the Administration Server, include the following Java option in the `weblogic.Server` command:

`-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true`

Or from the [Admin Console](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/logging/RedirectJVMOutput.html)

Comment: There is also `-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStderrToServerLogEnabled=true`