# Where to find the application log that deployed on weblogic server 10.3.5?

Tags: java, oracle, logging, deployment, weblogic

I am able to find the whole sever log under the path

`....\Oracle\WLS\user_projects\domains\[domain name goes here]\servers\[Server name goes here]\logs`

But the problem that I it does not contains all the stack that I usually see in `Jdeveloper` console at the development time.

So, Where to find the stack or logs for the application not the whole sever exactly like `Jdeveloper` console where every thing is shown even the print statements (`System.out.print()`) ?

Answer (score 6):

There are two potential locations (the one you mentioned is the default):

```
- <domain home>/servers/<server_name>/logs
- Admin Console->Servers->Server Name->Logging tab->Log file name
```

If you're not seeing the debug/stack traces you expect, you should use the `Advanced` section on the Logging tab and turn up the `Severity Level` for the log file and standard out.

You can also set `Redirect stdout logging enabled` and `Redirect stderr logging enabled` to ensure everything you expect gets to the log file.

That said, the application you are running could be using it's own logging location and ignore everything above.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @castling. I found these 2 answers that may help.

[Weblogic Logging Start Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112581/how-to-make-weblogic-log-all-console-message-into-a-file)

[Weblogic Enabling Redirect through Admin Console](http://myfusionlearnings.blogspot.com/2013/03/enable-logging-in-weblogic-to-print.html)

Answer (score 0):

Default weblogic domain will be under ".jdeveloper/system" folder in your home..  Under System folder, navigate to "DefaultDomain/servers/DefaultServer/logs"

Eg: 
/home/myuser/.jdeveloper/system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031/DefaultDomain/servers/DefaultServer/logs

Answer (score 0):

Open your startweblogic.cmd and add these properties. Make sure you give the path correctly..[Check the below image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6vIH.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).